# sending sms in twilio using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, random, twilio

twilio is work with me but I need to send the message to the number entered in the textbox by the user like (the name of the textbox is Phone_no)

```
  var phone = Phone_no.Text;
               var randomCode = rnd.Next(100000, 1000000);
                Session["codeNo"] = randomCode;

              var message = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

                  var sms = message.SendMessage("Caller ID", "phone" , "Your code is: " + randomCode, "");
                  Console.WriteLine(sms.Sid);
                Response.Redirect("nextpage.aspx");
```

so can you help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
       var phone = Phone_no.Text;
       var randomCode = rnd.Next(100000, 1000000);
        Session["codeNo"] = randomCode;

      var message = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

          var sms = message.SendMessage("Caller ID", phone , "Your code is: " + randomCode, "");
          Console.WriteLine(sms.Sid);
        Response.Redirect("nextpage.aspx");
```